# How to choose which library to use in a class (maven)?

Tags: java, json, spring, maven

I'm started working on an already existing project. In this project there is some JSON-parsing happening with the following exception being thrown by several methods:

```
JSONException.class
```

While I was unit-testing these parsers I couldn't import the right org.json.JSONException library.

The maven library used in the codebase was (package org.json.JSONException):

```
org.json:json:20160810
```

And the one that was importing in my tests was (package org.json.JSONException):

```
com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:0.0.20131108.vaadin1
```

I think the problem lies in both libraries share the same package names. When the test is execute the JSONException is thrown but the test still fails because its probably the other library. Anybody knows why this problem is happening and how to solve it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the concrete problem? What happens **precisely** when you compile (or run?) the code?

Comment: Can you post the block of your pom.xml with the dependencies and versions you are using?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to updated your pom.xml file and in the dependency section you can exclude a 3rd party dependency from a declared dependency. I guess in your case there is a dependency to json and vaadin, you'll find vaadin is also pulling the different version of json.

Answer (score 0):

You can try removing one of them. As suggested here:
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-deployer-kubernetes/issues/142